# Codename one : Attaching images to email message fails

Tags: android, image, email, codenameone

I'm trying to attach an image to an email Message, but when the local email client opens, it is not attached.

The Gmail client displays a ***Can't attach file*** message.

The Yahoo email client shows no warning but it doesn't attach the image either.

I'm using a Lenovo K6 with Android 7.0 device to test.

This is the code I used to attach the image to the email message:

```
Message m = new Message(content);
m.getAttachments().put(imgUri, "image/png");
```

Tried with "image/jpeg" as well but to no avail.

The file URI looks like this:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20171015_170852.jpg
```

I have even tried to move the image to a location under `FileSystemManager.getInstance().getAppHomePath()`
but it still didn't work.

Even if I'm using the Capture object to create a new image or picking an existent one form the gallery the result is the same. But if I manually attach an image from inside the email client everything works as expected.

The Android log isn't that helpful.

> 10-20 12:14:15.695 32049 32049 E Gmail   : Error adding attachment
>
> 10-20 12:14:15.695 32049 32049 E Gmail   : dsh: Failed to create local attachment
>
> 10-20 12:14:15.695 32049 32049 E Gmail   :    at dsi.a(SourceFile:132)
>
> 10-20 12:14:15.695 32049 32049 E Gmail   :    at cmd.a(SourceFile:1840)
>
> 10-20 12:14:15.695 32049 32049 E Gmail   :    at cmp.run(SourceFile:4)
>
> 10-20 12:14:15.695 32049 32049 E Gmail   :    at cmd.a(SourceFile:665)
>
> 10-20 12:14:15.695 32049 32049 E Gmail   :    at cmd.a(SourceFile:422)
>
> 10-20 12:14:15.695 32049 32049 E Gmail   :    at cmd.N(SourceFile:536)
>
> 10-20 12:14:15.695 32049 32049 E Gmail   :    at cmd.onCreate(SourceFile:181)
>
> 10-20 12:14:15.695 32049 32049 E Gmail   :    at com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail.onCreate(SourceFile:40)

I'm running out of options.
Any advice, please?

Comment: What is `m` ?..

Comment: m is codenameone Message object. Edited the original post to clarify that.

Comment: you should not expose uris with file:// schema

Comment: Android 7+ does not mind when using ACTION_SEND. Only with ACTION_VIEW. But indeed i was about to suggest to use a file provider.

Comment: I'm not progaming natively in Andoid, but I'm using codenameone.

Comment: Yes we know. But what about exposing file uris and using a file provider? You could react on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the attachment incorrectly. `getAttachments()` is used to return existing file URI and the mime type pair, not the best way to add an attachment.

Try this:

```
m.setAttachment(imgUri);
m.setAttachmentMimeType(Message.MIME_IMAGE_PNG);
```

Also, check the URI path and make sure it's correct as I could see this `file:///`.

I will also suggest that you place the file in your app home directory.

Comment: I do not see what is wrong with the path. Yours is the same as from OP.

Comment: I've been using m.getAttachments().put(imgUri, "image/png"); because that's how it is documented: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/messaging/Message.html

Comment: This worked. However, if one wants to add more attachments, it has to call m.getAttachments() after each setAttachment/setAttachmentMimeType, because otherwise it will simply overwrite the previous addition. A very peculiar method to add attachments indeed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"abc@gmail.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "attachment");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "PFA");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(destinationFile));//image file

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
```

Comment: It is not clear what you try to say. Please elaborate.

Comment: That's an Android native code for sending emails with attachments.